# appendChild of undefined when Append <input> element to <td>

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone here know how to fix this problem or having a similar problem? Please kindly tell me if i wrote the code wrong. Thanks before.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

//Getting table by id
var table = document.getElementById(str);

//Creating New Row
var row = document.createElement("tr");

//Creating New TD
var td1 = document.createElement('td');

//Creating new input.
var newInput= document.createElement('input');
newInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
newInput.setAttribute('class', 'quantity');

//Appending newInput to TD - Return Appendchild of undefined
td1.appenChild(newInput);

//Append td to tr
row.appendChild(td1);

//Append tr to table
table.children[0].appendChild(row);

</script>
```

Comment: Is "str" intended to be the name of an ID or a var with an ID name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `d` in the function name, `appenChild` should be `appendChild`:

```
//Appending newInput to TD - Return Appendchild of undefined
td1.appendChild(newInput);
```

Comment: OMG.. Looks like i need a new glasses!! Thanks for helping and thanks for noticing it for me!